# Как получить параметр передаваемый бат файлом C#?

Tags: c#, bat

Есть такой батник:

```
cd "D:\Program Files (x86)\xxxx\xxx\"
"D:\Program Files (x86)\xxxx\xxx\xx\3\3.exe" -"D:\Program Files (x86)\xxxx\xxx\Questions\2_2.png"
pause
```

Он запускает мою программу 3.exe и должен передавать ей **параметр**

```
"D:\Program Files (x86)\xxxx\xxx\Questions\2_2.png"
```

Вопрос в том, как мне этот параметр получить в WindowsForms приложение? Например в переменную **string fp;**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://ideone.com/ORYEby

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
  var fp = args[0];
```

> Это для консольного приложения как я понял, а для WindowsForms?

WinForms-приложение имеет файл Program.cs с функцией Main.

---

А впрочем, аргументы можно достать и другим способом:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
string fp = args[1]; // Тут в args[0] имя программы.
```

> Ругается на единичку( Что я делаю не так?

1. Вероятно, запускаешь без параметров.
   Следует проверять количество переданных аргументов.
2. В VS в настройках свойств проекта можно настроить запуск с параметрами.

Comment: В .NET пропускается argv[0] и в args[0] будет первый параметр командной строки?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, да. args - именно параметры. Чтобы докопаться до способа вызова надо лезть в `Environment.CommandLine` и парсить руками.

Comment: Ох они затейники...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, http://ideone.com/ORYEby

Comment: Это для консольного приложения как я понял, а для WindowsForms?

Comment: @user210281, там есть этот файл.

Comment: тоесть  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
     var fp = args[0];
         }
а потом в событии Form_Load можно вывести это значение label1.text=fp;??

Comment: @user210281, да, static. void или int - в зависимости от потребностей - шарп умеет оба.

Comment: В событии Form_Load можно вывести это значение label1.text=fp;??

Comment: @user210281, что-то я перемудрил. Можно проще.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()](//msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx) - тут с именем программы. Забавно. А меня когда-то парсить угораздило)))

Comment: вроде разобрался, спасибо=)

Comment: @Qwertiy на самом деле наличие имени программы в argv[] - исключительно подарок от запускающей стороны. Через CreateProcess можно задать произвольный argv[], включая argv[0]

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, а вот тут интереснее. Msdn: _"Первый элемент в массиве содержит имя файла исполняемой программы.Если имя файла не доступен, первый элемент равен String.Empty.Остальные элементы содержат все дополнительные лексемы, введенные в командной строке."_ Это тот случай, когда имя недоступно? Если нет, то когда оно недоступно?

Comment: На самом деле не «имя файла исполняемой программы», а «произвольная строка, контролируемая вызывающим процессом».

Comment: @VladD, а в каком случае она недоступна? О чём говорится в msdn?

Comment: @Qwertiy Ни разу не встречал нулевой argv[0] при ненулевом argv[1], но я исключительно с WinAPI работаю

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну мало ли как. Например, если нативный CLR-хост загружает Assembly из набора байт в памяти, и выполняет его (https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/ebb839f3218a9410f76f4595574155304c5e101e/src/mscorlib/src/System/Environment.cs#L579)